# android app uploaded says: does not supports tablets

Tags: android, uploading

When I uploaded my first apk on playstore console as draft they says its not actually compatible with tablets but actually it is. What I have ti change to make them convince?
I have already added support screen tag in my manifest for all screens.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your manifest file